# I can not figure out how to load second time posts at page end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using XMLHttpRequest to retreive more posts from mySQL database to show on the page.
It is working fine the first time, but the second time and times after that it doesn´t know which posts to acquire, so it will keep getting the second times over and over again.
What triggers the Send Request is not a button with a certain ID. It is a Load More Data At Page End. 
This is the code for Requesting XMLdata:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); } 
else  { 
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
wrap.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getposts.php?q="+nextId);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And here is the code for Load More Data At Page End:

```
function yHandler(){
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
if(y >= contentHeight)
{
//--- Requsting XMLdata goes here ---
}
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}
window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

I have tried to use $_SESSION for saving the time user has requested posts, so I can add +1 to it each time but the value will increase like crazy. First it is 0 then 4 and the third time it´ll be 9 or something like that. 
Here is how I use SESSION at the very first before HTML tag:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ordning']))
{
$_SESSION['ordning'] = $_SESSION['ordning'] + 1 ;
}
else
{
$_SESSION['ordning']=0;
}
```

Do anybody know of a way to do this? I am stuck like H ... l
Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nextId` is a reference to the first post that you want to retrieve from the XHR, you need to increase it each time you request the new posts, either by a set amount while sending the request or based on the number of responses you get from the server.

If it's not, you should add another parameter to the URL that you are requesting from the server such as `'&postIndex='+postIndex`, and increment `pageIndex` by the number of responses that you get from the server each time, as I mentioned above.

On the server side, simply start your SQL query from the data received in `pageIndex`.

Comment: nextId is the last id in the first page. It is "number of responses I get from the server" that I can´t figure out how. I want to add parameter to the URL request. But what is that parameter and how will the page save it for the next use?

Comment: You can save it either by making a global variable (generally frowned upon) or by saving the last index to a data attribute. If you're using jQuery, you can do this by calling `$("body").data("nextId", nextId)` (where nextId has been returned from the server as being the next ID that you need to load), and to retrieve the data to send it back to the server, you should call `$("body").data("nextId")`.
If not, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute

Comment: Do I use it like this: xmlhttp.open("GET","getposts.php?q="+nextId+"&sIndex="+$("body").data("nextId"));

Comment: Is there any other way other than XMLHttpRequest to retreive more posts from mySQL database? Because I am stuck!
I have tried to save the nextId in cookies, Sessions and text-files.
But ALL of them increase the value by 5 or 6 istead of just 1. 
I seems like the file is updated/reloaded 5 or 6 times after only ONE request. 
Please help!

Comment: @Max that is the correct way to implement it.
`if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` should only evaluate to true once, so if you increment `nextId` within that if statement, it should only increment when you receive new data from the server.
There are no other practical ways of retrieving the data that I am aware of.

Comment: But it won´t! It will execute the "getposts.php" several times. I even tried to put the index (times of retreiving data) in a databas table, to make sure it would happen only once. But now it is doing it even more: 40 times for each request.

Comment: Maybe it is the way that I trigger the XMLHttpRequest, has a "fault" in it.
`... if(y >= contentHeight) { //--- Requsting XMLdata --- }`

Comment: @Max you probably need to add another variable/attribute to store whether you are making a request, and set it to true when you send the request then don't make any more requests until it has been set to false after adding the new posts to the page (so once the page has been extended).

Comment: you´re probably right. I removed a "true" from the request link in order to put more variables there. 
`xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true)`
I will try with that and I will come back with the results.

Comment: No it didn´t help. I put the "true" in the request, but still the same problem. It seems like it is bouncing at the moment at which it reaches the bottom of the page. It´s bouncing forth and back between the first page and the SQL-page. So I need to make it happen only once.

Comment: @Max what I meant was have an attribute like `$(...).data("making-request", "false")`, and set it to true when you get to the bottom of the page. While the attribute is true, don't make any more requests, and when the request has completed and the page has been extended, set it back to false again to allow further requests to be made.

Comment: When you say "set it to true when you GET to the bottom of the page...", du you mean I put a code at the bottom like this: `<script>$(...).data("making-request", "true")</script>`

Comment: What I mean is this:

`if(y >= contentHeight && $("body").data("making-request") === "false")
{
    $("body").data("making-request", "true");
    [xhr request data]
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        wrap.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        $("body").data("making-request", "false");
    }
}`

Comment: Hi, It doesn´t work, I must have been missin something. "making-request" should this be as it is, or it has to be replaced by something else?

Comment: If you put it in the way I wrote it, but you will need to initialise it at the start of the program (`$("body").data("making-request", "false")`) in order for it to work.

Comment: I put it at the begining of the program, but it won´t fire the request at all. Can I show you my whole code somehow? I can´t paste it here, since there is no linebreak. I am desperate. Thanks